# Scum in dehumidifier bucket

Tags: basement, dehumidifier

I have a dehumidifier in the basement that runs pretty much constantly, and I go down there every day or so to empty the bucket.

After a while, scum starts to form on the interior of the bucket.  I try to keep this knocked down with vigorous spraying of hot water, and occasional disassembly and thorough scrubbing.

Lately I've been putting a bit of bleach (two tablespoons or so) in the bucket after I empty it.  Is this enough bleach to actually do anything?

Is there any better solution to this?  (I think that draining via a short hose running to the sump pit would be a better solution, but there aren't any open electrical outlets near the sump pit..)

Comment: Does 2tbsp of bleach in an unknown size bucket do anything? It probably does _something_, but what is your goal? Do disinfect? To prevent scum in the first place? What is the size of this bucket? More information would help.

Comment: @Bort Goal is to prevent formation of scum, so I don't have to manually scrub the bucket.  I believe it is 7.5 quart capacity.

Comment: I wonder how much scum there is in the sump pit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are spores of all sorts of things in the air in the basement. They land on the wet coils and drip into the bucket. Growth is not shocking. If you leave a light on down there, algae are likely. If not, other things grow just fine in the dark.

https://www.cdc.gov/disasters/bleach.html suggest 1 TBS bleach to one gallon of water, so 2 TBS to 1-7/8 gallons of water is, if anything, a bit more than they suggest for sanitizing.

*Use a longer hose (or pipe) to the sump, possibly elevating the dehumidifier to get adequate slope, given the reason you don't put it near the sump. Of course, if the sump has standing water in it, you should cover the sump (with holes for the pipes entering & leaving it) so it's not able to evaporate as much humidity back into the basement to be constantly recycled through the dehumidifier.*

Comment: Yeah, at one point I had a longish hose going from the dehumidifier to the sump, flat on the floor for most of its length, so it was always wet inside.  It eventually clogged, and some truly horrific gunk spewed out when I took it out to the driveway and forced water through it.  I don't use a hose for that anymore.

Comment: For the condensate-pump drain line in my basement, the contractor used transparent tubing that goes up to the rafters, across , then down to the drain. Since there's an air gap at the drain end, there's no chance of liquid siphoning back into the tube (in fact the last few feet tend to drain out), and the pump ought to keep it clear the rest of the way. Being transparent also means I can check it and find/clear clogs if necessary, though I've never had to.